# Azure Log Analytics StackTrace Incomplete

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have an .NET 6.0 app hosted in Azure's App Service with diagnostics set to log "App Service Console Logs" out to "Log Analytics Workspace" (Serilog is configured in the app to write to the console).

Then in Log Analytics Workspace I am trying to query errors logged out by my application.

I can see the error when querying the table "AppServiceAppLogs", but the StackTrace is only one line - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

How can I see the rest of the StackTrace information? There should be more lines showing the specific file and line number in code of where the problem is... But I can't see these details with any KQL query.

This reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/appserviceapplogs) says the StackTrace is complete, but where is the rest of it hiding?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure how if / how it's possible to see the complete StackTrace in Log Analytics..

BUT. I did find where the logs are stored and more information is kept in a file.

This file (`eventlog.xml`) can be found in Advanced Tools (Kudu) of the App Service, under the folder `LogFiles`